# git: detect if a github PR squash is a no-op

Tags: git, github

Background:

- A user sends me a github Pull Request with 3 commits.
- I review that PR and like it, but I want commits 1-2 squashed together.
- User squashes those commits and re-pushes.

How can I know that the net state of the PR has not changed?  I don't want to re-review it if literally the final state is identical.

Is there a fast way to get a checksum of the current content (but not commit sequence) of the tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A checksum of the ... content" would be the `TREE` hash from the commit.  So I guess you could

```
git log -n1 --format=%T
```

on each of the new and old commits, and see if the values match.

Or you could just use `git diff` to compare the commits' content (which will notice that the `TREE` hashes are the same and be done, so...)